# JBoss drools map line number from consequence exception to the actual rule consequence

Tags: drools

I am using  JBoss drools 5.1. My problem is when the consequence of the rule throws exception, it is hard to understand the line which caused the problem. For example in the below rule, it throws exception -

```
rule "exception handling"
when
then
    String str = null;
    str.length();
end
```

Below is the exception stack

```
Caused by: org.drools.runtime.rule.ConsequenceException: rule: exception handling

        at org.drools.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
        at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:927)
        at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:856)
        at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1071)
        at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:785)
        at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:751)
        at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:218)... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at defaultpkg.Rule_exception_handling_0.defaultConsequence(Rule_exception_handling_0.java:8)
        at defaultpkg.Rule_exception_handling_0DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Rule_exception_handling_0DefaultConsequenceInvoker.java:24)
        at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:917)
        ... 32 more
```

How to map the line number 8 to the line that caused the exception (in this case str.length())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is for you to submit a ticket for the Drools project and see if they can improve the exception handling and line mapping. They already map line numbers for lots of things, including debugging, but it seems that runtime consequence exceptions are not being mapped.

Meanwhile, it is not an ideal solution by any means, but you can dump generated classes to the  filesystem and look at them. The line numbers come from those classes. To do that, easiest way is to set a system property, for instance when you execute the application:

```
java -Ddrools.dump.dir=/tmp/classdump ...
```

Same option can be set on a configuration file or by API if you prefer. Check the Drools docs about how to do it.

Comment: Dump of the entire generated class is also very helpful. Line number in the exception would have been cool but I can live with the dump during development. Thanks.